# Meaning of dx/d

Tags: calculus

I was doing a differentiation problem, but I was stuck. I was given the acceleration as a function of position and I wanted to find the time it took for a certain position change to happen. My overall plan was to integrate the inverse of velocity given position bounds. Acceleration = (d^2x)/(dt^2) = velocity(d/(dt)). So if I was to set this equal to an expression and inverse both sides I get a (dt)/d, which I am not even sure is allowed?

Comment: $\frac{df}{dx}$ is *not* a fraction, you can't take the inverse of it to obtain $\frac {dx}{df}$. $\frac {d}{dx}$ is a operator (a function of a function that returns a function if you will) acting on $f$ to return the derivative of that function. It is not a fraction in the ordinary sense and can't be manipulated as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are playing much too "fast and loose" with your differential notation. Your goal is to get $t(x)-t(x_0)$. That is the same as $\int_{x_0}^x \frac{dt}{dy} dy$ (integral of the reciprocal of velocity against position). So you want to first get velocity as a function of position, and then integrate the reciprocal of that.

You know $a$. You want to integrate that $dt$ to get $v$, but you don't have a function of $t$, you have a function of $x$, so you can only integrate $dx$. So you multiply by $\frac{dt}{dx}$ and integrate $dx$. It now looks like

$$v(x)-v(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^x \frac{a(y)}{v(y)} dy.$$

This is writing $v$ in terms of $v$, which is bad, so let's instead differentiate both sides to get a differential equation:

$$\frac{dv}{dx}=a/v.$$

In separable form this is $v dv = a dx$, so

$$v(x)^2/2-v(x_0)^2/2=\int_{x_0}^x a(y) dy.$$

Thus assuming $v$ maintains one sign (which is necessary for several of the preceding steps as well), you have

$$v(x)=\operatorname{sign}(v(x_0)) \left ( v(x_0)^2 + 2 \int_{x_0}^x a(y) dy \right )^{1/2}.$$

Take the reciprocal of that and integrate it again to get the desired quantity.

Remark: physically, this derivation can be understood through the well-known facts $E(x)-E(x_0)=m \int_{x_0}^x a(y) dy$ and $E(x)=\frac{1}{2} m v(x)^2$, where $E$ is kinetic energy and $m$ is mass.